# app.config True vs true

Tags: .net, app-config, visual-studio-2013

According to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the following app.config entry is valid:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="false">
  <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Visual Studio will however complain that I have to write `True`/`False` for the `proxy` element while `false` is correct for `defaultProxy`:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="false">
  <proxy bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="False" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Are the values case sensitive? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bypassonlocal and usesystemdefault attributes do not map to boolean configuration properties, but values of the System.Net.Configuration.ProxyElement+BypassOnLocalValues and System.Net.Configuration.ProxyElement+UseSystemDefaultValues enums which include "Unspecified" as well as "True" and "False".

The enabled attribute on the defaultProxy element, on the other hand, is a boolean. For some reason the xsd schema is overly zealous and asks for lowercase values, but any casing would work at runtime.

In any case, I'd stick to what schema indicates.